# What's the relationship between bitbucket.org and bytebucket.org?

Tags: bitbucket

What is the relationship between bitbucket.org and bytebucket.org? Is the latter owned by the owners of the former, or is it some sort of scam?

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: Questions about source control are generally considered acceptable on SO, and these seem to be Mercurial-based source control hosts.

Comment: @Amadan: The bitbucket tag has 31 questions.

Comment: they are just friends, so I say go for it.

Comment: Right off hand, I'd guess that one is 8x bigger than the other

Answer (score 21, accepted):

bytebucket.org is owned by Bitbucket. It is/was used for serving files uploaded to the wiki repositories, to prevent cookie theft and the like if memory serves.

The rest of the domain should probably be configured to redirect.

Comment: Correct, Jesper Noerh has confirmed this a couple of times in the #bitbucket IRC channel. I don't think it's written down anywhere official, though.

Comment: Let me confirm that too. Bytebucket remains the domain from which we serve static content hosted by users (using "bitbucket hosted repos"). We do not issue session cookies for this domain to prevent csrf exploits.

Answer (score 8):

WHOIS records show that both bitbucket.org and bytebucket.org are registered to the same registrant.

They are also both running the same web server software. They're hosted in different netblocks, but both netblocks are owned by Amazon.com Inc.

I have an account at bitbucket.org.  I tried signing in at bytebucket.org but I'm having trouble reaching any https page at that site right now.  So I can't confirm that they have a common authentication between the two sites.

Okay, I have done a test: changing my account profile on bitbucket.org.  The change I made was reflected at bytebucket.org immediately.  It's still *possible* that bytebucket is a scam -- it might be a proxy to bitbucket.org, as an attempt to capture passwords.

Comment: After all of that evidence, it sounds like a safe guess that bitbucket just didn't want to lose users who misremembered the URL. "My buddy told me about this great site that would help me out. It was called byte bucket or something like that. Hey look, there it is." I've worked in many-a-company who bought URLs related to their main one for the eventuality of this possible conversation.

Comment: @Dinah: I agree with you.  This is the more likely reason for the two domains, but there's still a small possibility of doubt.

Comment: agreed. I'd initially be suspicious too just as the OP was, but I'd do the same research you did and after I would feel safe. It's not 100% conclusive but it's pretty convincing.

Comment: @Dinah if that was the case, they should make bytebucket.org redirect to bitbucket.org. That would make more sense to me, that way people are not confused about who owns the site.

Comment: @Metropolis: that's what I'd do as well, especially in the interest of not diluting the branding. There may have been a reason (including tech or marketing ignorance).

Comment: Looks like it's redirecting now!